# Joining CSV or Tables

Tags: python, sql, oracle, csv, pandas

I have two csv fies with different columns.
Table1

```
title   stage   jan      time
darn    3.001   0.421   5/23/2016 13:14
darn    2.054   0.1213  5/24/2016 14:14
ok      2.829   1.036   5/23/2016 14:14
five    1.115   1.146   5/23/2016 17:14
three      2       5    5/23/2016 21:14
```

Table 2

```
title   mar      apr     may    jun      date
darn    0.631   1.321   0.951   1.751   5/23/2016 12:14
ok      1.001   0.247   2.456   0.3216  5/24/2016 18:41
three   0.285   1.283   0.924   956     5/25/2016 17:41
```

I need to join them filtered by title(primary key) and the condition that the time in date field in table 2 is equal to (time - 1 hour) in date field in table 1. So the output should be something like this:

```
title   stage   jan     mar     apr     may    jun     date
 darn   3.001   0.421   0.631  1.321   0.951  1.751  5/23/2016 13:14
```

I was wondering if it can be done using Pandas or SQL query is the best way forward. I looked up and saw that pandas can merge based on unique key value.
    import pandas as pd

```
a = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
merged = a.merge(b, on='title')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

This is the program. I am struggling on how to set the condition for the date field.Bot SQL and Pandas solution is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a dummy column (to match "time" in `df`):

```
In [11]: df1["time"] = df1["date"] + pd.offsets.Hour(1)
```

Now you can merge cleanly:

```
In [12]: df.merge(df1)
Out[12]:
  title  stage    jan                time    mar    apr    may    jun                date
0  darn  3.001  0.421 2016-05-23 13:14:00  0.631  1.321  0.951  1.751 2016-05-23 12:14:00

In [13]: df.merge(df1, on=["title", "time"])  # potentially less reckless to specify columns
Out[13]:
  title  stage    jan                time    mar    apr    may    jun                date
0  darn  3.001  0.421 2016-05-23 13:14:00  0.631  1.321  0.951  1.751 2016-05-23 12:14:00
```

*Note: This means you don't have to do the complete merge (on just title) which potentially could be very space inefficient.*

Comment: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Hour' objects. It throws this error

Comment: @DigantaBharali it needs to be a datetime (not a string) column, you need to first `df["time"] = pd.to_datetame(df["time"])` and `df`["date"] = pd.to_datetame(df["date"])`. These are dates not strings, so they should be converted as such. You can also do this when reading in a csv using `parse_dates`.

Comment: everything works fine. Just that it fails to match the time columns, its giving me a null output with just the headers. Another question is during merge, can we give range like 'if it falls within one hour of the time' it will return that row?

Comment: @DigantaBharali within an hour is definitely a different problem (as you can only join on equal results). I recommend asking that as a new question, it's interesting (not sure I know the answer, will have a think).

Answer (score 1):

assuming your time and date variables are recognized as such by Pandas,
just add

```
merged = merged[merged.date == (merged.time - pd.Timedelta('1 hours'))]
```

Comment: But here you are not matching the date field. I don't think it would work if there are duplicate titles in table 1.

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'

Comment: you can filter after the matching. this should be the last line of your code.